# double tap and zoom on google map ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, zooming, pinch

There are two  delegate methods that telling map region is changed:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated  
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

My question is: 
Is there a way to detect the map region is changed from double tap or zooming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a gesture recognizer to detect the double tap:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

and do the same for the pinch zoom, with a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`

Comment: but the map already support the double tap and pinch,do you mean disable them and add gestures?

Comment: I mean that you can catch those gestures to set a flag or something that will help you understand if the region is changed due to a double tap or a zoom gesture. In your regionDidChangeAnimated you can check that flag and act accordingly